# Jquery set row background on click

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a jquery script for my html table so that when I click on a `tr` row, it sets its color. I was successful doing that with .css() but I want it so that when I click again on the same row I want the color to be set back to the default value (background color).

```
setTableRowColor:function(status) {
        if (status == true) {
            $("table tr").click(function(){
                $(this).css('background-color','red');                      
            });                 
        };
    },
```

Check: 
http://jsfiddle.net/R5GzS

So i dont know how to set css() callback to my default color.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to create a CSS class with the row color, then toggle the class:

```
$("table tr").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');                   
}); 

.active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Let me try that. If i create toogle class i can than call removeClass() right?

Comment: @Ikac -- You wont need to call `removeClass`, `toggleClass` takes care of that.

Comment: aham yeah i remeber that.

Answer (score 2):

Use a class instead and add/remove it via toggleClass():

```
setTableRowColor:function(status) {
    if (status == true) {
        $("table tr").click(function(){
            $(this).find('td').toggleClass('red');                      
        });                 
    };
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/R5GzS/1/)**